# WI-FI Problems on 18.10

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, 18.10

I realize there's a similar thread but since I didn't receive an answer over there I decided to create my own. My WiFi disconnects on its own and all I can do to fix it is restarting the network manager. Sometimes this happens once in a day, sometimes it happens every five minutes.

I've pasted output of `dmesg` [here](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2kwx).

Output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: enp1s0f0
version: 10
serial: 38:c9:86:07:28:a9
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 02
serial: 38:c9:86:e6:dc:d0
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.44 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service`

Comment: Should I wait to try this until I have WiFi problems again or can I run it now?